How do I order a barchart, but not by ascending or descending order?
I am making a bar chart breaking down time spent at each activity level(high, medium, low, and total active times) for individuals recorded to be in different fitness levels. here is the code I am using for my chart:
ggplot(temp_daily, aes(fill=ActivityType, y=ActivityTime, x=ActivityType)) +
geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity') +
facet_wrap(~ActivityLevel)+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=0.9))+
labs(title="Distribution of active time across each activity level grouping")

When the chart comes out, the order of the bars is:
High Activity Time - Low Activity Time - Medium Activity Time - Total Activity Time.
If I were to order it by the size of the bar, it would result in:
Total Activity Time - Low Activity Time- (depending on the group, it would vary here between Medium and High Activity Time).
I'd like to order it high to low, then total on the end. any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Please read this. You probably just need to reorder the factor levels of  ActivityLevel.
